# Is it possible to use a stored procedure to update three different tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I have an proc doing a select and update statements as follows. I need to incorporate the update statements and select statement which put the data into a temp table into a single sql select statement.

Is this possible?

```
             '
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Or googled for something like `multiple statements` `sql` `stored procedure`?

Comment: I have searched ..but only answers where a single table is only involved. This can be achieved by using case inside the select statement. But what causes the issue is , here in the update statement 3 tables are involved. The other fields in the tmp table shouldnt be affected by the update statement.

Comment: I think it depends on your DBMS.

Comment: the database is SQL server 2008.. do you have any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    valueA int
)

INSERT INTO 
    TableA
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure (@in_value int)
AS
    BEGIN

        --insert into temp table
        SELECT
            @in_value [out_value]
        INTO 
            #TestTable

        -- update with join on temp table
        UPDATE
            T
        SET
            T.[out_value] = 2
        FROM
            #TestTable T
            INNER JOIN TableA A on A.valueA = T.out_value
        WHERE
            A.valueA = 1

        -- update with join on temp table again
        UPDATE
            T
        SET
            [out_value] = 3
        FROM
            #TestTable T
            INNER JOIN TableA A on A.valueA = T.out_value
        WHERE
            A.valueA = 2

        --select results including the original "in_value"
        SELECT 
            *, 
            @in_value [in_value]
        FROM
            TableA A
            LEFT JOIN #TestTable T on T.out_value = A.valueA
    END;
GO

--execute stored procedure
EXEC test_procedure 1
```

Comment: i am not to use temp tables

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way out  by using union.
this is bit wierd but since i am not able to find anything else, settled with this method